# Locating the legend in Release Burndown Chart Code

Tags: charts, highcharts, rally

I'm working on modifying the Release Burndown Chart and would like to find where the legend is located in the code (i.e. The box at the bottom of the chart that tells which lines are associated with what values). I've looked through almost all the code in over 20 different files and can't seem to find it anywhere. I'm trying to locate what functionality/code is allowing the lines to show/hide on click and perhaps make one of the lines on the legend hide by default.

Here's the link to the src code for convenience: https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/charts/burndown

If anyone has any idea where I can move forward with this, I would be eternally grateful!

Thanks!!

Comment: Initial look in BurnDownChart.js shows they are not explicitly setting any chart legend options. You could roll your own. Take a look at the API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.

Answer (score 0):

As wergeld hinted at, this is highcharts default behavior (see the highcharts legendItemClick event).  To hide a series by default, you could set visible=false on the series.